# Classes in libraries not being picked up

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have various library dependencies in my build.sbt file

```
  scalaVersion := "2.10.5",
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.5" % "test",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1" % "provided",
    "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.2"
  ) map (_.excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "log4j"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.servlet")
  )),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(("org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.10")
    .excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "log4j"))),
  libraryDependencies += "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.16" % "test",
```

I can see them in my external libraries in the project view.

[image]

However, the classes in the libraries are not being picked up in the Scala source files. [image]

This is a sub module.
[image]
And the dependencies are declared in the parent, build.sbt. The code is in the child project.

I have tried:

1. Invalidating Caches / Restarts...
2. Deleting the .idea file and re-importing
3. Building project several times

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `FileUtils` is in `"commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.5"` and I don't see it in your list.

Comment: @Luca T. Tried that, updating question.

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies needs to be explicitly added also in the subproject.

For example, in your `build.sbt` in the root folder of your project you can set:

```
val commonDependencies = Seq(
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.5"
  // other dependencies
)

val root = (project in file(".")).settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies,
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    // dependencies only for project root
  )
)

val topWordsCounter = (project in file("top-words-counter"))
.settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies,
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    // dependencies only for the sub project project top-words-counter
  )
)
```

Hope this helps